# Running 50 models one after another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

in ArcGIS 10.3 I have 50 simple models I would like to run one after another. Im confused on the submodel process, currently I run each clicking from arccatalog, 50 in all. not a big deal but Id like to just click once and let it fly.

Note: Each Model has 1 iteration process within the Model.

currently Ive only run each model at a time, Ive tried to reasearch how to string them together via various website & help, but the iteration it seems is the stumbling issue.

Comment: Have you tried writing a model that invokes the models in succession?  Please **edit** the question to include your efforts to date.

Comment: nope, Im newish to the model world, I cant seem to see how to do that. it appears simple but Im missing it.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, a model can have only one iterator, so you can not copy the contents of each submodel having an iterator into one bigger model. Instead, depending on your needs:

1) If the models are ***totally*** independed (one model does not create output for the next model), you can simply throw all (sub)models into a "master" model and click run. It will process the models in an arbitrary order, probably the one in which they get added. This doesn't matter in this case, since the models are independed.

2) If the models are depended (one model creates output for the next one), you need to expose its output parameters by ***right*-clicking** the last (output) parameters, and choosing "Model Parameter", this will expose your output parameters to the "outside world". If you now add such a submodel to the "master", it will show its outputs and you can "chain" the models by using the connector tool to chain the output of one model to the next.

3) If the models are not really depended but need to run in a prefixed order, you can use the connector tool to connect the output parameter of the first model, ***to the main model icon of the second model*** (not to an input parameter!), and choose **Precondition**. This will ensure the second model only runs after the first models finishes and has generated output.

Comment: Marco, as I thought, I Missed the simplicty of connecting the output of each Model as a precondition to the next Model. Perfect!!!